# Page not found Error in WebView android

Tags: android, android-webview

I am trying to open URL in webview of my application, but I am getting "Page not found" error.
The same URL is not opening in my device(Android Tablet) browser also.

If I try to open this URL in my desktop browser, Its opening.

Please let me know how to solve this issue. Below is my code.

```
public class LinkCompanyPageWebView extends Activity{

private String url;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_webview);

    WebView wvbrowser;
    wvbrowser=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.wvbrowser);

    wvbrowser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wvbrowser.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);


    url = getIntent().getStringExtra("URL");
    wvbrowser.loadUrl(url);

    wvbrowser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                Log.i("WEB_VIEW_TEST", "error code:" + errorCode);
                super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
        }
     });

}
```

}

"onReceivedError"  not displaying any error.

p.s: Added Internet permissions to my app.